# C# Drawstring clear rectangle Or no rectangle? possible

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, drawing

here is the code i'm using, i really need to make it so the text does not appear inside of a box.  is that possible?

```
int width = (int)g.MeasureString(line, f).Width;
int height = (int)g.MeasureString(line,f).Height;
b = new Bitmap(b, new Size(width, height));
g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

g.Clear(Color.Empty);
g.DrawString(line,f, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
b.Save(savepoint+line+".tif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff); 
g.Flush();
```

What i mean is there can be no Rectangle around the text that is converted to image.  So I need to watch it to the same color  to create the illusion there is no box, or to never write out that rectangle period.

Comment: Please explain "does not appear inside of a box."  Are you saying that you get a border around it that you're trying to remove?  Or that you want to mask a rectangular area and only render the text outside that area?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: check edit/update please

Comment: What do you mean by a box? How do you use the image?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you mean. My test of drawing to a TIFF draws no "rectangle", and the code you posted will not draw anything.

Comment: Yes, scratch out something in mspaint and post it to tinypic.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the color Transparent for the backgtround and a file format that supports transparency, like PNG:

```
var measure = g.MeasureString(line, f);
int width = (int)measure.Width;
int height = (int)measure.Height;
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height)) {
  using (Graphics bg = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
    bg.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    using (Brush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)) {
      bg.DrawString(line, f, black, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  b.Save(savepoint+line+".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); 
}
```

I notice that you did overwrite your Graphics instance, didn't dispose the objects that you create, and called Graphics.Flush for no apparent reason...

Comment: And don't forget to properly parent the control. The "Transparent" background of a string really just sets the background to the Parent's.

Comment: keeps coming back with parameter not valid at using (b = new Bitmap(b, new Size(width, height)))

Comment: even otuside of the loop it still places a box around the text

Comment: @Mike: Where do you get the original graphics object from (variable g)? What loop are you talking about?

Comment: I do a foreach to get the line.  but there is still a blackbox being draw by the DrawString, the black outine of the text is the problem.

Comment: @Mike: The black box has to come from somewhere else. I tried the code, and as expected it doesn't draw any box around the text. How are you using the image?